# ReactJs: callback function is not called in case of this.setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/3535/ `this.setState` is called in `componentWillMount` with callback `this.loadData`. But the function `this.loadData` is never called as callback.

Comment: Please include the code from the fiddle in your question.  Also [#1740](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1740).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how the internals work here, but looking at the docs for [`setState()`](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate)...

> ...you can supply an optional callback function that is executed once `setState` is completed and the component is re-rendered.

...and the docs for [`componentWillMount()`](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentwillmount)...

> If you call `setState` within this method, `render()` will see the updated state and will be executed only once despite the state change.

...I assume it's related to the fact that calling `setState()` in `render()` doesn't queue up a re-render.

Given that, the most appropriate place to put an initial call to `loadData` would be [`componentDidMount()`](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount), which fires immediately after the initial render:

```
componentWillMount() {
  // ...
  this.setState({loaded, data});
},

componentDidMount() {
  this.loadData();
},
```